# how to connect to a drachtio server using drachtio-srf or drachtio module of nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I have installed **drachtio-server** and configured to default port of 9022 and localhost but when i am running my program using `drachtio-srf` for connecting with the **drachtio-server** it is showing me this error:

> srf error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $sudo iptables -F
 $sudo iptables -L
 $service drachtio-server start
```

or

```
 $service drachtio start
 $ netstat -alp | grep dra
```

or

```
$ netstat -alp | grep drachtio
```

SIP request are for port:5060 by default.